# igraph plot for multiple layers partition does not return expected output

Tags: python, igraph

Assume there are 3 time slices (i.e., `G_1`, `G_2`, `G_3`) that converted to `layers` via `time_slices_to_layers`. These layers and inter slices were then subject to `find_partition` to get their `communities`. However, plotting these partition does not result the expected output.

Here, the node interaction for each slice is as per the diagram below.

[image]

However, plotting the partition result give a incorrect `intraslice link` connection.

[image]

While the `interslice coupling`  should be random, but I expect the `intralsice link` should be maintain as below

[image]

May I know how to fix this issue.

I suspect this is due to wrongly assign the `vertex_label`

```
ig.plot(partition,vertex_label = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G'])
```

or it can be related to other configuration ?

The complete code to reproduce the above graph

```
import leidenalg as la
import igraph as ig
import numpy as np


A1 = np.array ( [[0., 0., 0., 0., 0,0,0],[5., 0., 0., 0., 0,0,0],[1., 0., 0., 0., 0,0,0],
                 [0., 1., 2., 0., 0,0,0],[0., 0., 0., 1., 0,0,0], [0., 0., 0., 1., 0,0,0],
                 [0., 0., 0., 0., 1,1,0]] )


A2 = np.array ( [[0., 0., 0., 0., 0,0,0],[5., 0., 0., 0., 0,0,0], [1., 0., 0., 0., 0,0,0],
                 [0., 1., 2., 0., 0,0,0], [0., 0., 0., 1., 0,0,0],[0., 0., 1., 1., 0,0,0],
                 [0., 0., 0., 0., 1,1,0]] )

A3 = np.array ( [[0., 0., 0., 0., 0,0,0], [0., 0., 0., 0., 0,0,0],[0., 0., 0., 0., 0,0,0],
                 [0., 1., 2., 0., 0,0,0],[0., 0., 0., 1., 0,0,0],[0., 0., 0., 1., 0,0,0],
                 [0., 0., 0., 0., 1,1,0]] )


G_1 = ig.Graph.Weighted_Adjacency ( A1.tolist () )
G_2 = ig.Graph.Weighted_Adjacency ( A2.tolist () )
G_3 = ig.Graph.Weighted_Adjacency ( A3.tolist () )
G_1.vs ['id'] = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G']
G_2.vs ['id'] = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G']
G_3.vs ['id'] = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G']

G_layers, G_interslice, G = la.time_slices_to_layers ( [G_1, G_2, G_3], interslice_weight=1,
                                                       slice_attr='slice', vertex_id_attr='id',
                                                       edge_type_attr='type', weight_attr='weight' )

partition = la.find_partition(G, la.CPMVertexPartition,resolution_parameter = 0.05);
ig.plot(partition,vertex_label = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G'])
```

---

[Cross-posted on igraph forum](https://igraph.discourse.group/t/igraph-plot-for-multiple-layers-partition-does-not-return-expected-output/844/3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit should be given to [Vincent Traag](https://igraph.discourse.group/u/vtraag) for the detail explaination.

Based on the creator feedback, the above issue can be resolve as below

```
# Convert from slices to layers
G_layers, G_interslice, G = la.time_slices_to_layers([G_1, G_2, G_3], interslice_weight=1e-1,
                                                     slice_attr='slice', vertex_id_attr='id')
# Create partitions
gamma = 0.3
partitions = [la.CPMVertexPartition(H, node_sizes='node_size',weights='weight',
                                    resolution_parameter=gamma) for H in G_layers]
interslice_partition = la.CPMVertexPartition(G_interslice, resolution_parameter=0,
                                             node_sizes='node_size', weights='weight')


# Detect communities
optimiser = la.Optimiser()
optimiser.set_rng_seed(11)
diff = optimiser.optimise_partition_multiplex(partitions + [interslice_partition])


# Plot network
partition_all = ig.VertexClustering(G, partitions[0].membership)
ig.plot(partition_all,
        vertex_label = [f'{v["id"]}-{v["slice"]}' for v in G.vs])
```

Which produced

[image]

In depth conversation can be found in the [igraph-forum](https://igraph.discourse.group/t/igraph-plot-for-multiple-layers-partition-does-not-return-expected-output/844/4?u=balandongiv)